# Memory error while saving django object

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have applied inheritance in my Django models structure as follows:

```
class SCUser(User):
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15,blank=True,null=True)
    address = JSONField(blank=True,null=True)
    photo = models.FileField(upload_to=SCUSER_PHOTOS,blank=True,null=True)
    is_registered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    registration_key = models.TextField(default='',blank=True,null=True)
    unseen_notifications = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Employee(SCUser):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=AvailabilityStatus)
```

I am almost done with complete project. **The problem is when I try to save SCUser or Employee Object, Almost 6 GB of memory is consumed and after that I got Memory Error**. Here are my error logs:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ec2-    user/virtualenvs/Snapcuffvnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 710, in save
force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/home/ec2-user/virtualenvs/Snapcuffvnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 738, in save_base
updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/home/ec2-user/virtualenvs/Snapcuffvnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 803, in _save_table
forced_update)
File "/home/ec2-user/virtualenvs/Snapcuffvnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 853, in _do_update
return filtered._update(values) > 0
  File "/home/ec2-user/virtualenvs/Snapcuffvnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 580, in _update
return query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(CURSOR)
  File "/home/ec2-user/virtualenvs/Snapcuffvnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1048, in execute_sql
cursor = super(SQLUpdateCompiler, self).execute_sql(result_type)
  File "/home/ec2-user/virtualenvs/Snapcuffvnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 829, in execute_sql
cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/ec2-user/virtualenvs/Snapcuffvnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 88, in execute
logger.debug('(%.3f) %s; args=%s' % (duration, sql, params),
MemoryError
```

I don't want to change my model structure since I have written a lot of code.

Comment: How much data are you storing in each record?  Do you have a lot of data stored in the database currently?  Are you getting the error when you save in the admin or in user code?  That sql query looks like the key. If you can turn on query logging or print it out, you might get some useful information.

Comment: In SCUser and Employee models, There are 10-12 records only. However in other models, There are thousands of records. I am getting this error while executing my code. Also from admin site, it is taking too longer to save the record

Comment: Could you show an SQL being executed?

Comment: have you over ridden the save method? do you have any pre_save signals?  have you looked at the slow query log in the database?

Comment: Solved. The problem was with JSONField address. Every time I used to save the object, escape character "\" was getting doubled. This was causing out of memory error. Thanks to all :-)